# Protected routes with next auth

Tags: authentication, cookies, next.js, next-auth

I have this code, i implemented the function nextAuthOptions because i receive cookies from backend i i need to store them in browser but i'm having problems when i want to validate that session on dashboard route because it returns undefined, i 'm out of options, i appreciate any answer, thanks!

```
export const nextAuthOptions: NextAuthOptionsCallback = (
  req,
  res
): NextAuthOptions => {
  console.log("req", req);
  console.log("res", res);
  return {
    // Configure one or more authentication providers
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
    providers: [
      // ...add more providers here

      Credentials({
        name: "Custom Login",
        credentials: {
          username: {
            label: "Correo:",
            type: "username",
            placeholder: "correo@google.com",
          },
          password: {
            label: "Contraseña:",
            type: "password",
            placeholder: "Contraseña",
          },
        },
        async authorize(credentials) {
          const user = await axiosHttpService.login(
            `http://localhost:3001/api/auth/login`,
            {
              username: credentials!.username,
              password: credentials!.password,
            }
          );
          const cookies = user.headers["set-cookie"];

          res.setHeader("set-cookie", cookies);

          return user.data.data;
        },
      }),
    ],

    session: {
      maxAge: 2592000, /// 30d
      strategy: "jwt",
      updateAge: 86400, // cada día
    },

    pages: {
      signIn: "/login",
    },

    callbacks: {
      async jwt({ token, account, user }) {
        token.accessToken = account?.accessToken;
        token.user = user;

        return token;
      },

      async session({ session, token, user }) {
        session.user = token.user as any;
        return session;
      },
    },
  };
};

export default (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  return NextAuth(req, res, nextAuthOptions(req, res));
};
```

```
export default function Dashboard() {
  const { data: session } = useSession();

  if (typeof window === "undefined") return null;

  if (session) {
    return (
      <>
        <h1>Protected Page</h1>
        <p>You can view this page because you are signed in.</p>
      </>
    );
  }
  return <p>Access Denied</p>;
}
export async function getServerSideProps(
  context: GetServerSidePropsContext
): Promise<GetServerSidePropsResult<any>> {
  const session = await getServerSession(
    context.req,
    context.res,
    nextAuthOptions(
      context.req as NextApiRequest,
      context.res as NextApiResponse
    )
  );

  return {
    props: {
      session,
    },
  };
}
```

i try to resolve with documentations and youtube videos